# Unable to connect to a Signal sent in a QTimer Slot if Slot is called before connecting the signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

Py3 / PySide2 5.13.2 on Windows

I have two classes: one clock emitting a Signal with a timer / one display printing the time

```
import PySide2
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot 

import time
import sys

class MyClock(QtCore.QObject):
    """
    Must inherited QObject to emit a Signal
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.start(1000.)
    
    def Start(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Tick)
                
    def Tick(self):
        t = time.time()
        print ("Emit: ",t)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("SEND(float)"),t)  
        
class ClockDisplay():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClockDisplay,self).__init__()

    def Display(self,t):
        print ("Received: ", t)
```

**BUG**: the QTimer slot (Tick) is called (clock.Start) BEFORE connecting the signal to display:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    clock = MyClock()
    clock.Start()

    display = ClockDisplay()

    clock.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL("SEND(float)"),display.Display)
```

**Warning Message
*** Sort Warning ***
Signals and slots in QMetaObject 'MyClock' are not ordered correctly, this may lead to issues.
1  Slot   Tick()
2! Signal SEND(float)
clock.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL("SEND(float)"),display.Display)**

and SEND is not received by display.

**WORKS** : the QTimer slot (Tick) is called (clock.Start) AFTER connecting the signal to display.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    clock = MyClock()

    display = ClockDisplay()

    clock.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL("SEND(float)"),display.Display)
    clock.Start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me in both cases they work only that I get the warning in the first case. This warning only indicates that the signals and slots are expected to be ordered in the QMetaObject but in this case they are not because first the "Tick" slot was added and then the "SEND" signal. Probably Qt or shiboken use the signals and slots in some way that requires some ordering, so it throws that warning.

My recommendation is that you don't use the old syntax of creating signals and slots but use "Signal" and "Slot":

```
from PySide2 import QtCore

import time
import sys


class MyClock(QtCore.QObject):
    SEND = QtCore.Signal(float)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.start(1000.0)

    def Start(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Tick)

    def Tick(self):
        t = time.time()
        print("Emit: ", t)
        self.SEND.emit(t)


class ClockDisplay:
    def Display(self, t):
        print("Received: ", t)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    clock = MyClock()
    clock.Start()

    display = ClockDisplay()

    clock.SEND.connect(display.Display)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```